# wait for a thread creation

Tags: c, multithreading

Is there a way to ensure that a thread was created before moving on to other instructions (without using a detour such as `sleep()`)?

I have a loop that looks something like this:

```
for(i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; ++i)
{
    if(pthread_create(&threads_id_array[i], NULL, ThreadFunction, &args))
    {
        perror("pthread_create() error");
        exit(1);
    }
    args.base += args.offset;   
}
```

Where `base` is a pointer to an array. I want to ensure that a thread was created before the promotion of `base` so that I can be sure that the thread's `args.base` holds the correct value. Currently, this causes bugs.

Comment: Is `args.base` set by the thread? Because there's a difference between a thread being created and having executed up to the point of setting the value.

Comment: when `pthread_create()` returns 0, the thread was "created". But whether it's started executing or waiting to be scheduled is something else. Do you want `args.base` to be updated only if the created completed or has executed something? It sounds like `args.base` is being accessed in a thread-unsafe manner (possibly data race). Post an [MCVE].

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo, `args.base` is set by main thread, and not by the created thread.

Comment: @l3x, i want each thread to get a specific, valid value of base. currently, i cant ensure that this is what will always happen - to the contrary: when debugging, i see that no thread get base, the second thread get base+offset, third thread get base+offset too, and last thread get a non-valid value of base (beyond base's end).

Comment: Look, don't do what you suggest.  Declare a struct type, I'll call it 'threadParams', dynamically-allocate a *threadParams with malloc, load it up with the parameter data required by the first thread and pass its address as the 'void*' creation parameter.  IMMEDIATELY then reseat the pointer in the main thread by mallocating another *threadParams for the next thread, so ensuring the the main thread can never again touch the  *threadParams that went to the first work thread.   Do that for all the work threads, and free the *threadParams in the work threads just before they exit.

Comment: You can make the main thread wait until the work thread has started running and has made a local copy of its params.  To do this, pass a semaphore as the thread parameter and wait on it in the main thread.  The work thread can signal it after its has copied it's params.  Try hard not to do this - send each thread its own parameters as above.

Comment: @MartinJames, Yeah, I dont want to use semaphore, or other sync tools. I'll try what you suggest.

Comment: @HeyJude Your question asks about "a way to ensure X before moving on" - that is precisely what synchronization primitives are *for*. And if you invoke them only once per thread's lifetime, you needn't worry about them slowing you down. Having said that, Martin's suggestion to dynamically allocate *args* and transfer their ownership to the thread is a much better (and idiomatic) way to proceed.

Comment: Thank you all. I eventually defined an array of `struct args` and passed each thread the appropriate index.

Comment: @HeyJude that is a common approach, often recommended, often seen, and makes it vey difficult to vary the number of threads at runtime, or even configure with a startup parameter.  I hate those 'store id, args etc. in an array' designs - too inflexible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are doing that to speed up some CPU-bound work, consider OpenMP instead of pthreads.

Like this:

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for(i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++)
{
    auto threadArgs = args;
    threadArgs.base += i * threadArgs.offset;
    ThreadFunction( &threadArgs );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Soonts answer and @Martin James comment, here's a snippet of another option - namely, using an array of structures, and sending each thread the respective index:

```
char *base_ptr =  base;
args_t args_array[NUM_THREADS];

for(i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; ++i)
{
    args_array[i].base = base_ptr;  
    base_ptr += args_array[i].offset;
}

for(i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; ++i)
{   
    if(pthread_create(&threads_id_array[i], NULL, ThreadFunction, &args_array[i]))
    {
        perror("pthread_create() error");
        exit(1);
    }
}
```